# Colors in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, colors

I'm struggling with Visual Studio 2008. I've used some form of "Zen" colors for more than I can remember. In VS2008 I keep getting one color that I cannot read and I have been unable to identify it; the purpose of the question is to avoid trial an error (the VS color interface is really ugly with no "real time" apply button).

If you look at the following picture, I'm debugging and the function on top has called the function below. The problem is that the calling line in upper function turns white (background) and is hard to read.

The question is: Does anybody know what exact setting will allow me to change that?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Sshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This describes the meaning of all those color options.

I think the one you are looking for is "Call Return"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw7t0545.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think that's your Call Return, under Text Editor.